# Getting $(1-3x^6 + 3x^{12} - x^{18}) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{i+2}{2} x^{i}$ from $(\frac{1-x^{6}}{1-x})^3$ using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm not sure how to get $(1-3x^6 + 3x^{12} - x^{18}) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{i+2}{2} x^{i}$ from $(\frac{1-x^{6}}{1-x})^3$.

I know the following series.

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1+x+x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...)$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^6}=(1+x^6+x^{12} + x^{18} + x^{24} + ...)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** From
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i,\quad |x|<1,
$$
by differentiating, you get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ix^{i-1},\quad |x|<1,
$$
or, changing $i-1$ to $i$, 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)x^{i},\quad |x|<1,
$$
differentiating again and changing $i-1$ to $i$ again :
$$
\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)(i+2)x^i,\quad |x|<1,
$$ then dividing by $2$ observing that
$$
\binom{i+2}{2} =\frac{(i+1)(i+2)}{2}
$$ leads to the desired result, taking into account that $$ \left(1-x^6\right)^3=1-3 x^6+3 x^{12}-x^{18}.$$